# The best way to translate Entity Objects to POJO and vice versa?

Tags: java, json, jpa, jersey

That's what I have seen on one project:
JPA Entity classes are used to persist objects to DB. 
But when we create Jersey endpoints, we normally consume and produce JSON. So, some kind of POJO's are used to represent the data we want send or receive.

So, every time a Jersey request is processed, "assembler" class is used to assemble a POJO from an entity object (or vice versa). So, the flow is something like this.
Entity Object -> assembler service -> JSON.

Now I am starting a new project, and I am not sure if this approach is the best one. From one point of view, it allows to control what I want to return as a JSON and separates these representations from the persistence classes. On the other hand, it looks like an extra layer to me which can be avoided.

Is there a way to make this translation easier (maybe automatically)?

UPDATE:
Thanks for answers. But POJO to JSON mapping is done by Jersey automatically. What I really wanted to know, is if there is a good way to map entity class (Java classes with JPA/Hibernate annotations) to JSON without using intermediate POJOs?

Comment: not sure, but you mean something like dozer?

Comment: Most of the Mapping Technologies like Jackson or Jersey automatically convert Object to JSON and vice versa , You need to just define a Java class that resembles the JSON you will be expecting.

Comment: json to pojo: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: JPA Enitties can be mapped to POJO in presentation, there are some tools for this purpose, dozer, modelMapper,etc. And serialization and deserializtion in json format, I think Jersey has native way to process this. For other Jaxrs implementations, such as RESTeasy in Wildfly, you can configure it using Jackson etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use what are sometimes called Projections. If there are fields on the entities that you don't want to expose on the REST API, you can implement an interface in the entity which only has a subset of the getters, and you then serialize only those parts to json.

You can have a look at [Spring Data REST](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) and how it's done there.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a nice Spring feature.